# Oracle : passing dynamic string in query through stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

If i am executing below query, it is giving me 4 correct records.

```
select SUBSCRIBER_NUM, SUBSCRIBER_STATUS, P_ID
from C_S_FORWARD_INFO
where SUBSCRIBER_NUM IN ('0', '07', '070', '0705', '07052', '070526', '0705262', '07052620') and
      SCP_VER = 1
```

But When i execute below, it is giving me 0 records. Actually I have to dynamically pass the value in 'IN' part of the query.

I tried below ( VAR_CALLING_NUM = 07052620):

```
while var1<=len LOOP 
temp1 := SUBSTR(VAR_CALLING_NUM, 1, var1); 
temp1 := concat('''',temp1); 
temp1 := concat(temp1,''''); 
temp6 := temp6 || temp1 || ',' ; 
var1:=var1+1; 
END LOOP; 
temp6 := SUBSTR(temp6, 1,length(temp6)-1);

select SUBSCRIBER_NUM, SUBSCRIBER_STATUS, P_ID from C_S_FORWARD_INFO where SUBSCRIBER_NUM IN ( temp6 ) and SCP_VER = 1 order by length(subscriber_num) desc;
```

Why this is givign me 0 records. Am i doing anything wrong, by passing temp6 in query like  `SUBSCRIBER_NUM IN ( temp6 )`

Comment: You have a loop code there so it is PL/SQL. In PL/SQL you can do select into some variable but not just select. Can you post whole your code please or just describe what do you want to do in PL/SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a string that looks like `"'0', '07', . . ."`.  This is a single string.  It is not interpreted as multiple values by the `in`.

You are going to need to use dynamic SQL to put this in as a list.  This requires constructing the SQL and then using `execute immediate`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actully I have a java code which is calling stored procedure. Now Stored procedure is so big, I have just shown some part of it here.  Can you tell me how do i do it.

Comment: Is it possible it store seperate values in variables. Like a1='07', a2='070', a3='0705', a4='07052' and do select SUBSCRIBER_NUM, SUBSCRIBER_STATUS, P_ID from C_S_FORWARD_INFO where SUBSCRIBER_NUM IN ( a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8) and SCP_VER = 1 order by length(subscriber_num) desc;

Comment: Your help is requested sir

Comment: @VJS . . . Yes, you can put each item in the `IN` list in as a separate parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below syntax to convert the values in single string to multiple strings to be valid for IN clause.

`(SELECT regexp_substr(YOUR_INPUT_VAR,'[^,]+', 1, level) AS list FROM dual CONNECT BY regexp_substr(YOUR_INPUT_VAR, '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL)`